# Using Boolean selection on a dataframe results in a KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I followed a code that plot the iris data set but it didn't work for me.
my dataset is as follow: two feature age and sex

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint
import random

sexe=[] 
for i in range(0,150):
    sexe.append(randint(0,1))
age=[]
for i in range(0,150):
    age.append(randint(18,65))
    
totaldata= {'age':age,
      'sexe': sexe,
      }

data=pd.DataFrame(totaldata, columns=['age','sexe'])
```

and the label are 4:

```
target_names=['danse', 'musique','cinema','theatre']
type_spectacle = list()
for i in range(0,150):
    type_spectacle.append(random.choice(target_names))
    
type_spectacle2=[]
for i in type_spectacle:
    if(i=="musique" ):
        type_spectacle2.append(0)
    elif (i=="cinema"):
        type_spectacle2.append(1)
    elif (i=="danse"):
        type_spectacle2.append(2)
    else :
        type_spectacle2.append(3)
```

then here is the plot code I tried

```
colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x_index = 4
for label, color in zip(range(len(target_names)), colors):
    ax.hist(data[type_spectacle2==label, x_index], 
            label=target_names[label],
            color=color)
    
ax.legend(loc='upper right')
fig.show()
```

I got this error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: (False, 4)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5bd6b0a0f9d3> in <module>
      5 x_index = 4
      6 for label, color in zip(range(len(target_names)), colors):
----> 7     ax.hist(data[type_spectacle2==label, x_index], 
      8             label=target_names[label],
      9             color=color)

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

e:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: (False, 4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two central problems:

- `type_spectacle2 == label` with `type_spectacle2` a Python list, gives just one value, `False`.  Converting `type_spectacle2` to a numpy array makes that `np.array(type_spectacle2) == label` gives a complete array of `True` and `False` values. You might want to read about the magic of [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).
- To extract one column of the dataframe, you can use `data[filter][columnname]`, where `filter` can be the boolean array from the previous point. And `columnname` the name of the column you want to extract.

Apart from that, when programming in Python, it is very helpful to get acquainted with [list comphrension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/). That way, lists can be constructed much easier.

Here is a minimal adaption of the code (using `gold` instead of `yellow` because `gold` is a bit darker):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint, choice

sexe = [randint(0, 1) for _ in range(0, 150)]
age = [randint(18, 65) for _ in range(0, 150)]
data = pd.DataFrame({'age': age, 'sexe': sexe, })

target_names = ['danse', 'musique', 'cinema', 'theatre']
type_spectacle = [choice(target_names) for _ in range(0, 150)]

spectacle_dict = {"musique": 0, "cinema": 1, "danse": 2, "theatre": 3}
type_spectacle2 = [spectacle_dict[spec] for spec in type_spectacle]

colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'gold']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, color in zip(range(len(target_names)), colors):
    ax.hist(data[np.array(type_spectacle2) == label]['age'], label=target_names[label], color=color, alpha=0.3)

ax.legend(loc='upper right')
fig.show()
```

[image: example plot]

The code can be simplified further if you would also use numpy to create the random arrays, as numpy creates such an array in one go with one simple function. Also, [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) can be used to create the [histograms](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) and automatically split per spectacle type. `sns.histplot()` has an option `multiple=` which can be set to `"stacked"` to stack the common bins on top of eachother. Or `multiple="layer"` to get layers similar to the original example.  There are also options to generate a curve similar to a probability density function (`kde=True`).

In that case, the code could look like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sexe = np.random.randint(0, 1, 150)
age = np.random.randint(18, 65, 150)
data = pd.DataFrame({'age': age, 'sexe': sexe, })

target_names = ['danse', 'musique', 'cinema', 'theatre']
type_spectacle = np.random.choice(target_names, 150)

spectacle_color_dict = {"musique": 'blue', "cinema": 'red', "danse": 'green', "theatre": 'gold'}
data['type spectacle'] = type_spectacle  # add a new column

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.histplot(data, x='age', hue='type spectacle', palette=spectacle_color_dict, multiple='stack', ax=ax)
fig.show()
```

[image: seaborn plot]